# ES6 Compilation Issue in IE

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript

I am Currently Working on One of the Applications which works on Chrome using Angular2/ES6.

However,Client wants the same Application to run on IE.I am aware of IE NOT Supporting ES6.Just wanted to know ,if there is a way the same Can be Achieved.

P.S - I am doing Build from my Visual Studio 2015,and below is my tsconfig.json.

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "es6",
"module": "commonjs",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"sourceMap": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"removeComments": false,
"noImplicitAny": false
}
}
```

Is there any way I can use 2 targets,such that Other Works as fallback?

Comment: Why not just target `es5` or lower?

Comment: @Saravana....es5 and lower does not support many of Typescript functionalities,like Promises,map etc.

Comment: You can use a polyfill like [es6-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promise) and still target es5 or lower.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep your ES6 JavaScript intact by using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to compile ES6 scripts to ES5, and it's possible to use Babel with Angular 2 without sacrificing the use of TypeScript, as shown in [this article](https://shuheikagawa.com/blog/2016/05/08/angular-2-with-babel/):

> How to use it
>
> ```
> npm install -D babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-angular2
> ```
>
> Add presets to .babelrc. Note that the presets' order is important.
>
> ```
> {
>     "presets": ["es2015", "angular2"]
> }
> ```
>
> See [babel-angular2-app](https://github.com/shuhei/babel-angular2-app) for more complete example.