# Issue while deploying WebPage on IIS

Tags: angular, iis-7

I am facing a very peculiar situation and is Related to one of my Question.

[ES6 Compilation Issue in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42975894/es6-compilation-issue-in-ie)

I have been able to get my Web Page Up and Running on IE from local host.However,Now the Issue Occurs when I deploy my Web Page on IIS.I start getting Syntax Error Issue in System JS. I am using same Files in both the scenario.

All the Required Files are present in the Link.

Updated tsconfig.json:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "es6",
"module": "commonjs",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"sourceMap": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
 "removeComments": false,
"noImplicitAny": false
  },
"exclude": [
   "node_modules",
    "typings"
]
}
```

Comment: why u are using iis-7

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI.....For Testing purpose